# Issues in Testing SMO SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am new be in SVM  and  SMO algorithm, I implemented SMO using the pseudocode provided in : “Fast training of support vector machines using SMO” by John platt.

I am finding issues testing my implementation.
Can anyone provide me with  data sets having small features, can you also provide me  their optimal SMO (C and tolérance) parameters.
 I am also finding issues tuning these parameters.

Thank  you
regards

Fast Training of Support Vector Machines
using Sequential Minimal Optimization

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "small features"?